# Can hyperosmiacs (people w/super sonic smell) smell pheromones? How powerful is their sense of smell?

Tags: sweat, smell, nostrils, pheromones

Can hyperosmiacs (people w/super sonic smell) smell pheromones? How powerful is their sense of smell?

Is there a chart that shows the degree to which they smell things in comparison to the rest of us?

Is it a life-long thing? Or is a temporary thing?

Any articles/blogs by a hyperosmiac?

Comment: What do you mean by "pheromones"? It is a very generic catch-all term and everybody defines it differently. Also, even in normal-smelling people, not everybody can smell the same compounds, so the question seems rather unanswerable.